# Spreadsheet stops working after creating a new sheet using a script and deleting exceeding col/rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every time I create a new sheet using a script, my Spreadsheet stops working after a while and I have to kill the browser tab.

The problem happens after I correctly create the new sheet and I use the following two statements to delete the exceeding columns and rows.

```
ss.deleteColumns(firstCol, colNb);
ss.deleteRows(firstRow, rowNb);
```

I have tried commenting the above and the Spreadsheet doesn't stop.

Do you have any idea, please?

Thanks,

Comment: try flushing the spreadsheet after that line by using SpreadsheetApp.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you are declaring your variables, it is hard to say. Generally I use ss for the spreadsheet that contains the individual sheets, and sheet for a particular sheet I am working on. <s>If this is the case for you, it appears you may be trying to do an action that is limited to individual sheets on the spreadsheet container.</s>

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sheet
;
sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

Additionally, it may be best to test whether your sheet has the additional columns and rows you are trying to remove.

```
if (sheet.getMaxColumns() > lastCol) {
  sheet.deleteColumns(lastCol +1, sheet.getMaxColumns() -lastCol);
}
if (sheet.getMaxRows() > lastRow) {
  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow +1, sheet.getMaxRows() -lastRow);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Reno Blair, thanks for your comment and my apologies for this late reply. 
Actually, the sheet had the additional columns and rows I tried to delete. Indeed, I had to mention that the two methods deleted the exceeded rows and columns correctly before the spreadsheet got frozen. 

I removed the two functions and I haven't tried yet, but it would be useful to understand what could have caused it.